# WebP format not working in IE browser

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, cross-browser, webp

I have been trying to compress icons and  images used in my application ,so that the application will render fast. I used **WebP** tool for doing the same.I came to notice that Google chrome supported the format easily,but IE browser doesn't.
I have been getting the below error in IE console:

```
HTTP401: DENIED - The requested resource requires user authentication.
GET - http://localhost:8081/undefined
```

also with warning as :

```
DOM7009: Unable to decode image at URL ..
```

I also used the library  - **webpjs-0.0.2.min.js(latest)** for cross browser support,but still the problem exists - IE not allowing to load .webp formats.

Comment: The first console error has something to do with your application logic. The js code running on your IE browser cannot decode some variable the result of which is the GET call to the undefined endpoint. As for the webp rendering issue, that is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47663490/how-to-view-webp-format-on-ie11/56021203#56021203